# Raya sobre abreviaturas

Tags: historia, ortografía, abreviaturas

En un local de tapeo de mi ciudad hay un cartel, precioso por cierto, anunciando una corrida de toros de 1891. Y entre el texto aparecen varias abreviaturas:

[image: detalle de abreviaturas]

Se puede ver que algunas de las abreviaturas como Exmo., Exma. y Sra., además del punto habitual al final, llevan también un especie de raya encima; pero otras como Sr. o D. no la llevan.

**¿Cuál era la función de esta raya? ¿Qué reglas seguía su utilización? ¿Cuándo empezó a usarse, cuándo se dejó de hacerlo, y por qué?**

**Añado**: buscando información sobre esto, **he encontrado menciones de algo llamado "lineta"** que a veces se usaba en la Edad Media para indicar abreviaturas. **¿Tiene algo que ver?** Y en tal caso, ¿qué pinta en un cartel cinco siglos posterior?

Comment: My German mother-in-law, born in 1928, only got up to 3rd grade, in the war. She used to put bars over certain vowels in her handwriting, e.g. over a U without an umlaut (the two dots). My spouse says she was showing the difference between the two types of U. But for me it was NOT fun to read.  The dots weren't very percussive and therefore looked similar to the bar in appearance. Her flowy pen made the two dots run together.  Result, all the Us, with umlaut and without, looked the same to me. Something about your image reminds me of her "helpful" bars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La *Ortografía castellana* de la RAE tuvo varias ediciones, pero por la época del cartel que presentas (finales del siglo XIX) la obra había sufrido un parón. En la web de la RAE se listan [las ediciones](http://www.rae.es/sites/default/files/Tabla_ediciones_Ortografia.pdf) (PDF), y desde 1820 hasta 1969 no se publicaron ediciones nuevas, solamente algunos recopilatorios, como el *Prontuario de ortografía de la lengua castellana en preguntas y respuestas* de 1870 (que también tuvo sucesivas ediciones).

Sin embargo, podemos consultar esa edición de 1820 de la *Ortografía* [en Google Books](https://books.google.es/books?id=UicSAAAAIAAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=es#v=onepage&q&f=false). Lo bueno es que tiene un capítulo entero dedicado a las abreviaturas (ver páginas 135 y siguientes), que comienza así:

[image: Abreviaturas]

Como ves, nada más empezar el capítulo cita dos ejemplos usando la virgulilla sobre toda la abreviatura, además del punto. Tanto la virgulilla como la raya eran comunes en las abreviaturas, pero también lo eran las letras voladas. Lo más curioso es que a lo largo de todo el capítulo no explica cómo se deben abreviar las palabras, si con la virgulilla, con letras voladas, o de otra forma. Simplemente dan una lista de las abreviaturas más comunes, cada cual con su estilo diferente, como puedes ver en la siguiente imagen:

[image: Ejemplos]

El enredo está servido. La palabra "doctor" se abrevia con una letra volada, pero "doctores" no, solo duplica la inicial, "dicho" va con raya, "derecho" con virgulilla, "diciembre" de nuevo con letras voladas, y así toda la lista.

Para los casos concretos de las abreviaturas que aparecen en el cartel, leemos:

[image: Excelentísimo]

[image: Señor]

Parece que la forma correcta por entonces era ya usar las letras voladas en estas abreviaturas, así que entiendo que el cartel usa la raya o bien por motivos de estilo, para recrear una forma más antigua de abreviatura, o bien por la confusión entre los diferentes estilos existentes. Véase por ejemplo que algunas abreviaturas se admitían en diferentes estilos por entonces:

[image: guarde]

En todo caso, la función de esa raya o de la virgulilla era la misma: delimitar la abreviatura. Dado que la función de delimitación de la abreviatura pasó a ser el punto, su uso fue decayendo y de hecho en la edición de la *Ortografía* de 1820 ya son pocas las abreviaturas que hacen uso de la virgulilla y muchas menos de la raya. Su origen viene de antiguo, ya en la Edad Media y antes en textos en latín vulgar se usaban abreviaturas como estas para ahorrar papel, sobre todo en la caligrafía de amanuense. Puedes consultar [la Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scribal_abbreviation#Suspension) para más información, en el caso de la raya o virgulilla eran signos para indicar una abreviatura por suspensión (se indicaba el principio de la palabra pero no el final) de tipo general.

Revisando el texto del *Prontuario* no veo que diga nada acerca de las abreviaturas más allá de que "solo se deben usar las ya establecidas para evitar confusiones". Y ya en ediciones modernas de la *Ortografía* (como la actual de 2010) no se habla para nada de estas rayas o virgulillas para indicar abreviaturas.

Answer (score 6):

**En las abreviaturas por contracción se usa un trazo o una virguilla sobre ellas.** Tengo entendido que aún se usan; tal vez no con la misma frecuencia, ni en todos los contextos por igual, pero en la escuela secundaria nos enseñaron a usarlas  (México). Por ejemplo (en computadoras y máquinas de escribir es más común usar la virguilla, pero también puedes poner la raya sobre toda la palabra):

- Merced = `m̃d`.
- Excelentísima = `Ex̃ma`.
- Centavo = `c̃tv`.
- Fábrica = `f̃ca`.

Si no mal recuerdo, sus reglas de uso son:

1. Sólo se usa en abreviaturas por contracción. Por ejemplo, es incorrecto su uso en abreviaturas por apócope (`dir.`, `sig.`, `pág.`) o síncope (`Dr.`, `Sr.`).
2. Si se usa la virguilla, se pone en la primera consonante de la abreviatura.

Comment: @walen (y al prm296) el uso data desde hace mucho tiempo, hasta en el latín y griego.  Con la venida de la imprenta, se solía poner un solo tilde/macrón encima de una sola letra, en vez de toda la palabra como fuera la práctica antes.  Por ejemplo, *nr̃o*, abreviatura muy frecuente en los incunables para *nuestro*, era *n︢r︦o︣* (si no se muestra la mar de bien, sería como *n͠ro*) en los manuscritos de aquel día.  Desafortunadamente, Unicode no prevé buena forma de poner un tilde alargado encima de varias letras.

Comment: @walen en los proximos días puedo tomar algunos ejemplos de un texto con que estoy trabajando: tengo una edición manuscrita basada en una edición impresa del año 1492. Pero desafortunadamente hoy no tengo el tiempo :-(