# Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1917 (note 2 of 2)

Tags: identificación-de-término

For the year 1917 in my great-grandfathers Civil Guard records there are two entries.

Here is the second note (split over two pages):

[image]

[image]

This is the transcription so far:

> Por R. O. de 22 de Agosto año marginal “[D. O. nº 187](http://www.bibliotecavirtualdefensa.es/BVMDefensa/es/catalogo_imagenes/grupo.do?path=10714)” se dan las
> gracias a este indº (individuo) por la conducto observada en los
> servicios **provocados** por los agitadores del orden, **imponiendo** el rápido
> restablecimiento de la tranquilidad publica en el puesto de Badolatosa
> finió el año.
>
> El Comandante Mayor

I know that at-least two words are not correct but there may be more. And I believe I have found the relevant **Diario Oficial** bulletin but I am not sure which page has the related information.

---

#### Bulletin 187

I think the relevant article is actually on page 1 as I see similar words:

[image]

I have not tried to translate that article yet to learn about it.

---

#### Update

I replaced two words based on the bulletin content. I think they are correct and don't know if the transcribed text has more issues?

---

### Related Questions

[Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1917 (note 1 of 2)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39487/28260)

Comment: it says _finó_, which is a conjugation of the verb _finar_ that means 'to die'.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' No, this can't be. My great-grandfather has more notes in this document up to 1930. And I know he was still in the Civil Guard in 1942. I also know that he did not actually die until 1965 in Valencia as I have his death certificate and confirmation of where he was buried in the city.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' We had that discussion a few notes ago. It's the verb finir https://dle.rae.es/finir

Comment: @RubioRic oh, so interesting. I didn't know _finir_ exists as a verb, so seeing _finó_ made me think only in the verb _finar_. Both mean to end, but clearly this one you explain has more sense, since it does not involve dying. Thanks

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' I didn't know it either. It's used a lot in these notes to indicate in which post he finished the year. Alive. ;-P

Comment: Relevant context: [Spanish crisis of 1917](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_crisis_of_1917). Those were tough years and few years later, in 1923, there was a coup d'etat by precisely the man mentioned here: Miguel Primo de Rivera.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' Great link. But I think that you're mixing two different Primo de Riveras. The one signing almost all articles in the bulletin is its uncle Fernando, Minister of War at that time https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fernando_Primo_de_Rivera

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' I didn't now it until I searched because I found strange all those articles signed.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle You got almost the complete text. Just missed the final a in conducta and a stop before "en el puesto de Badolatosa finió el año" that makes the E capital.

Comment: @RubioRic oh wow, I stand corrected again :D I didn't know, either. So there are not two, but three famous Primo de Rivera in the Spanish history. I didn't cross check because I recalled Miguel PdR being the captain of Catalonia, but now I see that was a bit later, by 1922

Comment: @RubioRic I added an answer with your minor changes and included an initial translation.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' Is it worth fleshing out your link with a bit of information as a second answer? Entirely up to you.

Comment: I see @RubioRic did so, providing extra information. Thanks! This thread has been of a great learning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me gather in this answer various links provided by @fedorqui and me in comments that provide the historical context.

---

Probably the events in which Andrew's ancestor got involved were part of the Spanish Crisis of 1917 ([EN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_crisis_of_1917)) ([ES](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crisis_espa%C3%B1ola_de_1917)). Due to his previous records probably he did "concentration services" (crowd-control) during a revolutionary strike ([ES](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huelga_general_en_Espa%C3%B1a_de_1917)) that took place in August of that year.

[image: Guardia Civil members doing concentration services during the revolutionary strike of 1917 in Madrid]

The picture above has been taken from [this article](https://www.larioja.com/la-rioja/huelga-revolucionaria-1917-20170814000956-ntvo.html) where it was labelled "Detención de un huelguista en Madrid que es conducido por una pareja de la Guardia Civil a caballo en una imagen del 15 de agosto de 1917. / MARÍN"

---

The person that signed all articles contained in the [referenced official bulletin](http://www.bibliotecavirtualdefensa.es/BVMDefensa/es/catalogo_imagenes/grupo.do?path=10714) was [Fernando Primo de Rivera y Sobremonte](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fernando_Primo_de_Rivera), Minister of War at that time. Not to be confused with his nephew [Fernando Primo de Rivera y Orbaneja](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fernando_Primo_de_Rivera_y_Orbaneja) nor his other nephew [Miguel Primo de Rivera y Orbaneja](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miguel_Primo_de_Rivera), that later leaded a successful coup d'etat and was the father of [José Antonio Primo de Rivera](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jos%C3%A9_Antonio_Primo_de_Rivera). What a saga!

Comment: This is really useful. I have been told in the past that comments might not always remain and that it is worth moving important ones into answers. Now I got to pick an answer to accept - mine or yours! Decisions decisions. 

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments by @RubioRic this is the final transcribed text:

> Por R. O. [Real Orden] de 22 de Agosto año marginal “D. O. nº 187” se
> dan las gracias a este indº (individuo) por la conducta observada en
> los servicios provocados por los agitadores del orden, imponiendo el
> rápido restablecimiento de la tranquilidad pública. En el puesto de
> Badolatosa finió el año.
>
> El Comandante Mayor

---

#### Translation

This is the translation:

> By R. O. [Royal Order] of 22 August marginal year "D. O. nº 187"
> thanks are given to this individual for the conduct observed in the
> services provoked by the agitators of order, imposing the rapid
> re-establishment of public tranquillity. The year ended at the
> Badolatosa post.
>
> The Major Commander

Feel free to comment on any issues with the translation. Also feel free to either edit my answer or add another with a little bit of the background to the situation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the transcription of the last sentence is wrong. First, the verb 'finir' is not in common use nowadays (except in Colombia, according to the DRAE definition) and I don't think it was used or understood in the early 20th century either. But even if it was, the sentence 'En el puesto de Badolatosa finió el año' doesn't make any sense. I think the last sentence is simply the standard formula used at the time before a signature in this type of document. It should be 'En el puesto de Badolatosa firmó el excmo.' (It could be a different abbreviation, similar to 'excmo.'). For the old-fashioned use of a dash over handwritten abbreviations see: [Raya sobre abreviaturas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/28890/30925)

There is also a typo in the transcription of the second line. 'conducto' should be 'conducta'.